# Java, FileWriter(file, true) dosen't append on file

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, computer-vision, netbeans-8

i have a Runnable thread that refresh every 5 seconds.
This thread want to write on file named with time and date.

i check if file exists, i want to append the new update on the existed file and, when minute change, generate a new file and do the same on it every 5 seconds.

The application is based on JFrame Application Form

```
Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable(){

    @override
    public void run(){
        try{
            String FileName = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ".txt";

            File f = new File(FileName);
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(FileName);
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);

            FileWriter filewriter2 = new FileWriter(f, true);
            BufferedWriter = bufferedWriter2 = new BufferedWriter(filewriter2);

            if (f.isFile() && !f.isDirectory()){ 
                bufferedWriter2.write("Hello"); //this part doesn't append "Hello" in file (as i want) but overwrite the existing file
                bufferedWriter2.close();
            }else{
                bufferedWriter.write("Hello"); //this part must overwrite the existing file so i think this work
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }

        } catch (IOExcception ex){
            Logger.getLogger(Gestionale.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,nell,ex);
        }
    }
};
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
SchedulateFuture<?> ez = executor.scheduleFixedRate(helloRunnable,0,5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always instantiating a `FileWriter` that overwrites an existing file.

```
FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(FileName);
```

After this line the file will always be empty.
You have to move the creation of the `FileWriter` objects into the if statement.